# Show members random and not in alphabetical order

Tags: php

On the memberpage its shows the first 16 members, they are all in alphabetical order.
How to change that into random.

```
<?php


$limit=48;
$stages ='none';

$page = isset($_GET['page'])?mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']):0;
$start = ($page !== 0)?($page - 1) * $limit:0;

$queryl ="select *, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(birthdate)), '%Y')+0 as age from user_profiles LIMIT ".$start.",".$limit;
$query = "SELECT count(*) as num  FROM `user_profiles`  ";
$targetpage = 'zoeken.php?'.rtrim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],'&');
$dis = display($queryl);
$paginate = paginate2($page, $stages, $limit, $targetpage, $query, $start);//current page, stages, limit, query 
echo $dis['thumbnail'];

?>
```

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY rand()`. But, when you use pagination with `limit` in the query, It's not a good idea to fetch data in random order. Because the data in page 2 might have duplicates from page 1.

Answer (score 0):

Select a random row with MySQL:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1

select *, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(birthdate)), '%Y')+0 as age from user_profiles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$start.",".$limit;
```